# Why don't member function temporaries bind to the right type?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose that we have the following base and derived classes:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Car {
public:
    void Drive() { std::cout << "Baby, can I drive your car?" << std::endl; }
};

class Porsche : public Car {
};
```

..and also the following template function:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
void Function(void (T::*m1)(void), void (V::*m2)(void)) {
    std::cout << (m1 == m2) << std::endl;
}
```

Why does this compile using GCC:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void (Porsche::*ptr)(void) = &Porsche::Drive;
    Function(ptr, ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

...but not this?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void (Porsche::*ptr)(void) = &Porsche::Drive;
    Function(&Porsche::Drive, ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tested it with g++ 4.0.1 under MacOSX and both compiled fine, both with non-virtual and with virtual pointers when both pointers refer to the same method in the same class.

Comment: Really?  I also compiled the exact same code under OSX.  It gave the following error: 
    Test2.cpp: In function ‘void Function(void (T::*)(), void (V::*)()) [with T = Car, V = Porsche]’:
    Test2.cpp:25:   instantiated from here
    Test2.cpp:17: error: invalid operands of types ‘void (Car::*)()’ and ‘void (Porsche::*)()’ to binary ‘operator==’

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    void (Porsche::*ptr)(void) = &Porsche::Drive;
    Function(&Porsche::Drive, ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

`ptr` has type `void (Porsche::*)()`, but `&Porsche::Drive` has type `void (Car::*)()` (because the member is found in `Car`, not in `Porsche`). Thus the function called compares these two member pointers with those types, and the standard says

> In addition, pointers to members can be compared, or a pointer to member and a null pointer constant. Pointer to member conversions (4.11) and qualification conversions (4.4) are performed to bring them to a common type. If one operand is a null pointer constant, the common type is the type of the other operand. Otherwise, the common type is a pointer to member type similar (4.4) to the type of one of the operands, with a cv-qualification signature (4.4) that is the union of the cv-qualification signatures of the operand types.

`4.11` describes an implicit Standard conversion from `void (Base::*)()` to `void (Derived::*)()`. Thus, the comparison would find the common type `void (Porsche::*)()`. For an object of type `Porsche`, both member pointers would refer to the same function (which is `Car::Drive`) - so the comparison would yield true. The [comeau web compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) follows this interpretation and compiles your code.

Comment: Given your statement, I don't understand why the conversion `void (Porsche::*ptr)(void) = &Porsche::Drive` is valid.  Shouldn't `void (Car::*ptr)(void) = &Car::Drive` be the only valid assignment in this case?

Comment: A derived class is guaranteed to contain the members of its base classes. That's why `T Base::*` converts implicitly to `T Derived::*` (it's reverse to the usual conversion of `Derived*` to `Base*`).

Comment: According to 4.11 the following declaration should work also? `template <typename T> void Function(void (T::*m1)(void), void (T::*m2)(void))`

Comment: No that won't work with that call in main, because `T` will be deduced to both `Porsche` and `Car`, which is a contradiction.

Comment: So basically, whenever &Porsche::Drive is passed to a template method like the comparison function I described, it will automatically be cast to void (Car::*)(void) because Drive is defined on Car? Or does this behavior depend on the context of the template?

Comment: Its type itself is `void(Car::*)()` - it doesn't need to be converted first.

Comment: @litb, I just checked myself. +1 to your answer, it is exactly what I thought. I cannot write so quickly in English yet :)

Answer (score 1):

With g++ 4.0.1 the examples you provide compile fine, but it has problems dealing with comparisons of member function pointers of different types (even if the compared element is a virtual method.

```
struct base
{
   void f() {}
   virtual void g() {}
};
struct derived : public base
{
   void f() {}
   virtual void g() {}
};
template <typename T, typename U>
bool cmp( void (T::*lhs)(), void (U::*rhs)() ) {
   return lhs == rhs;
}
int main()
{
   void (base::*bp)() = &base::f;
   void (base::*bvp)() = &base::g;

   cmp( bp, &base::f );  // compiles
   cmp( bvp, &base::g ); // compiles

   void (derived::*dp)() = &derived::f;
   void (derived::*dvp)() = &derived::g;

   cmp( dp, &derived::f );  // compiles
   cmp( dvp, &derived::g ); // compiles

   cmp( bp, dp );   // fails to compile
   cmp( bvp, dvp ); // fails to compile
}
```

Now, I have tested the same with comeau online compiler and the whole code compiles fine. I cannot tell you right away what is the standard behavior. I will have to browse the standard for a while.

EDIT: I guess not, litb already did.